# SQL query to get the correct column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to create a query that shows whether the employees has taken what kind of leave on time card in the below format

```
Person_Number          Overtime_measure_hours      Regular_Measure_hours                Others_code        Others_measure 
11                          8                           9                                 Extra shift       9
11                          8                           9                                   Double          0.8
11                          8                           9                               Weekend shift         8
```

I have created the below query for this -

```
select
person_number
,SUM(CASE WHEN atrb.attribute_category = 'Overtime' THEN atrb.measure measure_hours END) AS Overtime_measure_hours
, SUM(CASE WHEN atrb.attribute_category LIKE 'Regular P%' THEN atrb.measure measure_hours END) AS Regular_Measure_hours
, MAX(CASE WHEN atrb.attribute_category IN ( 'Double','Weekend shift','Extra shift') THEN atrb.attribute_category END) AS Others_code
, SUM(CASE WHEN atrb.attribute_category NOT IN ('Overtime','Regular Pay') THEN atrb.measure measure_hours END) AS Others_measure
,file_id
FROM
(
SELECT papf.person_number
,rec.file_id
,rec.start_time

FROM hwm_tm_rec AS rec
CROSS JOIN per_all_people_F AS papf
JOIN fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrb_usages AS ausage
  ON ​ausage.usages_source_id = rec.tm_rec_id
​ AND ausage.usages_source_version = rec.tm_rec_version
JOIN fusion.hwm_tm_rep_atrbs AS atrb
  ​ON atrb.tm_rep_atrb_id = ausage.tm_rep_atrb_id
JOIN hwm_tm_statuses AS status
  ON status.tm_bldg_blk_id = rec.tm_rec_id
​ AND status.tm_bldg_blk_version = rec.tm_rec_version
WHERE 1=1
  AND papf.person_number = '11'
  AND rec.tm_rec_type IN ('RANGE', 'MEASURE') 
  AND TRUNC(status.date_to) = TO_DATE('31/12/4712', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND atrb.attribute_category IN ('Overtime','Regular', 'Double','Weekend shift','Extra shift')
  AND TRUNC(sh21.start_time) BETWEEN TRUNC(:P_From_Date) AND TRUNC(:P_To_Date)
  )
GROUP BY person_number,
,file_id
```

But the above query is giving me the output like -

```
Person_Number          Overtime_measure_hours      Regular_Measure_hours                Others_code        Others_measure 
11                          8                           9                                 Extra shift       9
11                          8                           9                                   Extra shift     0.8
11                          8                           9                               Extra shiftt         8
```

The cause of the above result is using max in the column Others_code

If  i remove it the output comes like -

```
Person_Number          Overtime_measure_hours      Regular_Measure_hours                Others_code        Others_measure 
11                          8                           9                                 
11                                                                                      Extra shift         9
11                                                                                          Double          0.8
11                                                                                      Weekend shift         8
```

All the other things in query are getting picked correctly. What function should i use to get the expecetd output

Comment: Can you check your example queries and output? You do a `group by` on person_number but there are still multiple rows with the same person_number (which should not be possible).

Comment: Thanks for correcting, i have tweaked teh query a bit. The issue i am having is with the Others_code . any possible solution would be helpful

Comment: This query can also not run because you use the alias `atrb` in the main query while it only exists in the inline table. It's hard to troubleshoot where you're going wrong here. Please try to be concise.